# Load a URL of a photo to Magento's Shopping Cart

Tags: magento, url, jpeg

I have built a filter in my database that will deliver information to a Magento Website for shopping of our products. We have over 200,000 photos of our products loaded in Amazon's Cloud. Each photo has its own URL like this: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/gigabitps/0-008-2-19-06-SU-52-00-19P31P-3.JPG` 
We may have several photos for one product that would be `-1.JPG`, `-2.JPG`, `-3.JPG`.

Can you advise on how to load a photo URL to Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Magento's default behavior is to expect it to be in charge of your media (photo) files.  If your goal is to have Magento simply contain a collection of photo URLs then you should research third party extensions, or your own custom extension.

It should be noted that if Magento has no control over the images then you'll lose a lot of its image functionality.  Typically you load the original photos in Magento, then request them at whatever dimensions you need.  Magento will generate and write a scaled image for these requests and update the URL accordingly.